# How to make an image the full width of a screen with dictating the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I created an image slider, but I am running into an issue. I want the width of the images to be the entire width of the screen; I accomplished this. However, my images' height are more than 100% of the height of the screen. I am wanting the height to be around 50-70% of the screen (preferably 50%). I tried adding `height: 70vh;` to my images, but that did not help.

Can anyone suggest something to help this?

My slider can be viewed at: http://realtorcatch.com/slider3

My code is:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*height: 70vh;*/
}
.cycle-slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cycle-prev {
    left: 10%;
}
.cycle-next {
    right: 10%;
}
.cycle-pager {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cycle-pager span {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
    <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
    <img src="images/subway.jpg" alt="subway">
    <img src="images/beach.jpg" alt="beach">
    <img src="images/space.jpg" alt="space">
</div>
```

Comment: If you want 100% by width and height than just add `height:100vh; width:100%;`. It must work, if you still have the issue share it.

Comment: That made the image not be 100% width.

Comment: Image is already 100% by width in your demo link. Check [here](http://i.imgur.com/fp2v5md.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it is now, but the height is the entire page. That is my issue with it. I am only wanting the height to be around 50% of the page.

Comment: So you could do is take three `div` side by side with your prefered dimensions(width and height), then place the images as background so you could set the `background-size:cover;` or whatever eles you prefer and make those 3 div's slide.

Comment: This is the only way not to make your image shrink.

Comment: @divy3993 I am unsure of what you mean.

Comment: Check this [image](http://i.imgur.com/HqnPbUd.png).

Comment: Not going to lie, that confused me even more.

Answer (score 1):

On your `img` declaration, instead of `max-width` set `width` to 100% and `height` to `70vh`. If you'd like more variety in the height, try setting the `min-height` to be 50vh and the `max-height` to be 70vh.

Be warned, this will skew your images and make them look disproportionate.

**Alternate solution:**

Create a "scrim". By this, I mean create a box that covers up the bottom half of the page. You can actually do this with a pseudo-element from your wrapper:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.cycle-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%; //50% of parent element
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I was just going to state that. It makes the images distorted now. You can see what I mean if you go to it now.

Comment: so you can't have it both ways. either you're going to distort the image by setting both dimensions or you're going to let it automatically resize itself by setting one dimension.

Comment: Then how do other sliders get the images to be only that size of the page?

Comment: a lot of them probably use images that are the proportion they want already. others may use a scrim, like the one i've mentioned above.

Comment: hmmm. Just tried that and I am not seeing what it is doing differently.

Comment: ehhh... try setting `img { position: relative; z-index: 1; }`

Comment: oh. it's because of whatever JS you're using is setting the z-index of your images to 99. Set your z-index of the scrim to something higher, say 100. you also didn't set the bg color of your scrim.

Comment: I hate to keep bringing back bad news. I changed the `z-index` to 1000 and it didn't help.

Comment: set the background color. you forgot to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99751/discussion-between-jason-and-becky).

Comment: of this? `.cycle-slideshow:after`? I have that set to the white as you had it.

Answer (score 0):

change style of img to img {width: 100%; height: 100vh;}

It will work for you. Thank you.

Comment: If you make height 70vh images will shrink.

Comment: Then how can I make this work without shrinking the images? That is the whole point. I want the width to be 100%, but this not to be the entire screen in height.

Answer (score 0):

try this,, Hope it will help you.

```
var vHeight = $(window).height()/2,  // for 50%
vWidth = $(window).width(),
```